# (UWP) How to animate Flyout object

Tags: c#, .net, xaml, uwp

I'm making a Flyout object. Everything works fine, I just want to make it slide in to the window in a certain direction instead of flash in. Can anybody give an example or tutorial? Thank you!

Comment: Use `DoubleAnimation` to control `Margin`
Or control `Canvas.Top/Left/Right/Bottom` if element in the `Canvas`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [Edge-based UI animations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/motion/motion-edgebased).

> But the Flyout has built-in animations. it's not really edge-based UI, because they should be associated with the context that caused them to display, not with the app window edge. It may be that you use flyouts for UI that's invoked from an AppBar, but that's still a different situation than pure edge UI. From [Edge-based animations in default Windows Runtime control behavior](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/apps/jj649428(v=win.10)#edge-based-animations-in-default-windows-runtime-control-behavior).

If you want to apply `EdgeUIThemeTransition` for the Flyout. You could edit its FlyoutPresenterStyle like the following:

```
<Style x:Key="FlyoutFlyoutPresenterStyle1" TargetType="FlyoutPresenter">
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
        <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
        <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="False"/>
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{ThemeResource FlyoutPresenterBackground}"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{ThemeResource FlyoutBorderThemeBrush}"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="{ThemeResource FlyoutBorderThemeThickness}"/>
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="{ThemeResource FlyoutContentThemePadding}"/>
        <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="{ThemeResource FlyoutThemeMinWidth}"/>
        <Setter Property="MaxWidth" Value="{ThemeResource FlyoutThemeMaxWidth}"/>
        <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="{ThemeResource FlyoutThemeMinHeight}"/>
        <Setter Property="MaxHeight" Value="{ThemeResource FlyoutThemeMaxHeight}"/>
        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollMode" Value="Auto"/>
        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Auto"/>
        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollMode" Value="Auto"/>
        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Auto"/>
        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.ZoomMode" Value="Disabled"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="FlyoutPresenter">
                    <Border BackgroundSizing="OuterBorderEdge" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" CornerRadius="{TemplateBinding CornerRadius}" Padding="{ThemeResource FlyoutBorderThemePadding}">
                        <Border.Transitions>
                            <TransitionCollection>
                                <EdgeUIThemeTransition Edge="Right"></EdgeUIThemeTransition>
                            </TransitionCollection>
                        </Border.Transitions>
                        <ScrollViewer x:Name="ScrollViewer" AutomationProperties.AccessibilityView="Raw" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility}" HorizontalScrollMode="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollMode}" VerticalScrollMode="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollMode}" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility}" ZoomMode="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.ZoomMode}">
                            <ContentPresenter ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" ContentTransitions="{TemplateBinding ContentTransitions}" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                        </ScrollViewer>
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

And then, you could apply this style for your Flyout.

```
<Page.BottomAppBar>
    <CommandBar>
        <AppBarButton Label="Flyout" Icon="Flag" >
            <AppBarButton.Flyout>
                <Flyout FlyoutPresenterStyle="{StaticResource FlyoutFlyoutPresenterStyle1}">
                    <Grid Height="500" Width="300" Background="LightBlue">
                    </Grid>
                </Flyout>
            </AppBarButton.Flyout>
        </AppBarButton>
    </CommandBar>
</Page.BottomAppBar>
```